# How do you get amplitude of audio file in Android before you play it?

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, visualization, android-audiomanager

I know we can easily do it when we record it (several ways, actually). But how are we going about getting an amplitude graph from an mp3/ogg file?

As it is now, I see two options:
 1. Quickly play it & construct it while its playing
 2. Try to do it with ffmpeg (but I really don't want to do NDK)

Are there any other options beside these? Thank you

Comment: maybe this will help you [link](https://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/record-play-and-visualize-raw-audio-data-in-android). I found it very useful when I tried to build a sound analyzer.

Comment: @AlexandruMihaila Hi! Unfortunatelly, it only touches the audio you record in realtime. My use case is different, I need to do the same with prerecorded one.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: I did not find a universal solution but I've managed to get the data from one of the formats by reading it by bytes

Comment: Can you explain more about how you did that? @McMillanMe

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use my library [Amplituda](https://github.com/lincollincol/Amplituda) which calculate amplitudes from audio and provide it in different formats like json, list of integers and sequences.

If you want to draw a waveform from amplitudes data, you can directly use my [WaveformSeekBar library](https://github.com/lincollincol/waveformSeekBar) fork in which Amplituda implemented.

Comment: Getting issue when upload android bundle to play store using your lib. The issue is: This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.
The following APKs or app bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: [19]
Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code that it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app.

Comment: It gives me wrong amplitude values, different from ones privided by MediaRecorder